# Как найти контуры объекта в Open CV Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, opencv, машинное-зрение

Есть фотография знака на дороге, и есть код, который его выделяет. Как найти у знака контуры, и вырезать его по ним?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
znak_image = cv2.imread('znaki.jpg')
print(type(znak_image), znak_image.shape)
 
low_blue = (116, 32, 7)
high_blue = (133,46,19)
only_znak = cv2.inRange(znak_image, low_blue, high_blue)
cv2.imshow('only znak', only_znak)
cv2.waitKey(0)
znak_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(znak_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #Преобразуем в HSV
znak_color_low = (100, 180, 100) 
znak_color_high = (130, 250, 250) 
only_znak_hsv = cv2.inRange(znak_hsv, znak_color_low, znak_color_high)
cv2.imshow('znak_color_hsv', only_znak_hsv)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Знак найден](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9jmv.png)

Comment: Дальше морфологией чистите от "пыли" , и ищите положение знака ф-циями cv2.findNonZero; cv2.boundingRect

Comment: Вам подходит моё решение? Если так, то отметьте его как верное, либо уточните, что в нём не хватает?

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас есть задача найти контуры знака -- это одна задача. Её можно решить с помощью различных фильтров: [canny](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) или [так](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=edge%20detection&type=Repositories).

Но мне кажется, что Ваша задача в том, чтобы выделить сам знак, о чём Вы и сообщаете. В таком случае, вам нужно решать задачу сегментации. Эта задача совсем другого уровня сложности. Вы можете попробовать придумывать эвристики. Либо воспользоваться поиском по [гитхабу](https://github.com/search?q=road%20sign%20segmentation&type=Repositories) или kaggle.